# How to make condition for exception variable in calculated field that compatible with parameter

Tags: parameters, set, tableau-api, calculated-field

I have a question for combining parameter and sets.

Let's say i have created a parameter to change measure dynamically. And i need to combine each measure with 1 sets, except for 1 sets. This is the general story

Parameter:
Measure A
Measure B
Measure C
Measure D

Sets:
Set A
Set B
Set C

First i created a calculated field to make sets compatible with measure.

[Set Filters]->Calculated Field Name

```
if [Set A] THEN "Measure A"
elseif [Set B] THEN "Measure B"
elseif [Set C] THEN "Measure C"
else "Measure D"
END
```

Then I created another calculated field called "Set Filter Parameter" to connect [Set Filters] with [Test Parameter]->Parameter Name

[Set Filter Parameter]

```
[Set Filters] = [Parameters].[Test Parameter]
```

The reason why i think i should make "Measure D" into else, because i don't need any Sets for "Measure D", so it will show the value just like it its.

But the result it just going weel for Measure A, Measure B and Measure C. Measure D got the wrong value.

How do i make only Measure D that not combine with Sets.

Edited:

Link https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/24b56becf6c50e7bc88dd73c6d9e44f120160205165221/cc13063032d51cb20ee3e62564f788c320160205165221/778f8c

So the purpose is,I want to show the number of the variable same as each sheet.
For coffee, the number should be same with "Coffee Drinker" Sheet
For herbal drink, the number should be same with "Herbal Drinker" Sheet
For tea, the number should be same with "Tea Drinker" Sheet
And for milk, the number should be same with Milk varibale on "Total" Sheet

So milk is the only variable that no need to be filtered by sets

Thanks

Randy

Comment: Could you please share your work? I think that it could be really useful to understand what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Hi Fabio, i add the information and the workbook on the first post. Feel free to ask if something is not clear. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks, Randy

Comment: I am unable to understand if there is any reason behind using `SET` . Can it be tried same using calculated fields

Comment: HI minatverma, how to do it with calculated field? I dont get the idea. Thanks